# While developing in Swift for an iOS app, how do we check for a trusted environment?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, mobile

While scanning our iOS app, the tool flagged the app for:
"The application does not check to ensure the operating environment can be trusted."
We just can not seem to find any information about what exactly this issue is. Looking at reports of other scanned apps, some have this but many do not.
Thank you in advance

Links from Report:
https://owasp.org/www-project-mobile-top-10/2016-risks/m9-reverse-engineering
https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/284.html

[image: Report]

Comment: I don't know anything about this tool, but it could be referring to using the [DeviceCheck](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck) framework

Comment: Thanks George. Looking at DeviceCheck, it seems like it is used if you are communicating with your server. Our app doesn't communicate with our servers for anything.
By the name of the finding, it seems like you are supposed to use a framework to check that the OS it is installed on is trusted.

Comment: I think it may be just for the server, yes. I know there are ways of checking for jailbreaks which are quite hacky imo (e.g. testing if the app can access what would normally be a protected file). This may be why they suggest using an open-source library with that functionality since it gets complex very quickly, and requires extensive knowledge about how to detect a jailbreak. However, I don't see why this is essential if it can't be used as a malicious actor against your server or anyone else. The jailbreak only affects them then in this case.

Comment: There is the risk of reading a file on a jailbroken device as an example. Since it is rooted, any app or the OS itself can change a file's contents so it can no longer be trusted when it was before presumed to be safe. This is where the attack vector really comes from - the app can't trust _almost anything_. If you want to fix this warning, I'm sure there is something open-source out there but I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: This is often flagged by various tools, but it's questionable item really. First of all, is jailbroken device really a bad news? depends which app you are developing. Maybe for professional app it's unacceptable, but for game, or general use app... who am I to tell the user to not jailbreak their device? Second: there's no 100% way to disable your app on jailbroken devices (like even Apple admits). So instead of any "checks", I'd rather put an effort that even if someone is able to get to any files on jail-broken device, they won't be able to get any value of them...

Comment: A basic truism of information security is that you cannot trust a device you don't physically control. You can use techniques like app attestation to validate that specific, high value, requests come from an unmodified version of your app but any checks for the state of the device itself, that execute on the device, are susceptible to falsification since you cannot trust the device...  I agree this is quite a questionable finding in practice

Answer (score 0):

This was the response when I queried the scanning tool (Kryptowire) about this finding:
The trusted environment check refers to the application checking for things such as Root access or Jailbreaks on the device. There are several open source projects that can help with this functionality such as Rootbeer for Android (https://github.com/scottyab/rootbeer) and for iOS there is DTTJailbreakDetection (https://github.com/thii/DTTJailbreakDetection).